# GoLang: Unable to send the email with attachment

Tags: go, email

I am trying to send an email with attachment using the below code:

```
package mail

import (
    "bytes"
    logging "project/logging"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "mime/multipart"
    "net/textproto"

    "gopkg.in/mail.v2"
)

func SendWithAttachment(from string, to []string, subject, bodyHTML string, attachmentName string, attachmentData []byte) error {
    logoURL := "/path/to/cs.jpg"
    m := mail.NewMessage()
    m.SetHeader("From", from)
    m.SetHeader("To", to...)
    m.SetHeader("Subject", subject)
    m.Embed(logoURL)

    // Create a multipart message
    body := &bytes.Buffer{}
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)

    // Add HTML part
    htmlPart := make(textproto.MIMEHeader)
    htmlPart.Set("Content-Type", "text/html")
    htmlPart.Set("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "quoted-printable")
    htmlPartWriter, err := writer.CreatePart(htmlPart)
    if err != nil {
        logging.NewDefaultLogger().Errorf("Error creating html part: %s", err)
        return err
    }
    htmlPartWriter.Write([]byte(bodyHTML))

    // Add Attachment part
    attachmentPart := make(textproto.MIMEHeader)
    attachmentPart.Set("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
    attachmentPart.Set("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64")
    attachmentPart.Set("Content-Disposition", `attachment; filename="`+attachmentName+`"`)
    attachmentPartWriter, err := writer.CreatePart(attachmentPart)
    if err != nil {
        logging.NewDefaultLogger().Errorf("Error creating attachment part: %s", err)
        return err
    }
    attachmentPartWriter.Write(attachmentData)

    writer.Close()

    m.SetBody("multipart/mixed", body.String())

    fmt.Printf("Sending mail.....")
    err = gs.dialer.DialAndSend(m)
    if err != nil {
        logging.NewDefaultLogger().Errorf("Error sending email..: %s", err)
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

The body content and attachment content both comes as an attachment in a file named "noname".

**Contents of the attachment file is as follows:**

--d885a04b467ae7d6100eb844c09574a6bdaef0a9796dc6fdde03a90613c9
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/html

...
  
    
--d885a04b467ae7d6100eb844c09574a6bdaef0a9796dc6fdde03a90613c9
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="resource_details.csv"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

attachment content..

--d885a04b467ae7d6100eb844c09574a6bdaef0a9796dc6fdde03a90613c9--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working with:

```
    m := mail.NewMessage()
    m.SetHeader("From", emailDetails.From)
    m.SetHeader("To", emailDetails.To...)
    m.SetHeader("Subject", emailDetails.Subject)

    if emailDetails.BodyHTML != "" {
        m.SetBody("text/html", emailDetails.BodyHTML)
    } else {
        m.SetBody("text/plain", emailDetails.BodyPlain)
    }

    if emailDetails.AttachmentName != "" && len(emailDetails.AttachmentData) > 0 {
        m.Attach(emailDetails.AttachmentName, mail.SetCopyFunc(func(writer io.Writer) error {
            _, err := writer.Write(emailDetails.AttachmentData)
            return err
        }))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
package mail

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "mime/multipart"
    "net/smtp"
    "net/textproto"
)

func SendWithAttachment(from string, to []string, subject, bodyHTML string, attachmentName string, attachmentData []byte) error {
    m := NewMessage()
    m.SetHeader("From", from)
    m.SetHeader("To", to...)
    m.SetHeader("Subject", subject)

    // Create a multipart message
    body := &bytes.Buffer{}
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)

    // Set the boundary string for both the outer and attachment parts
    boundary := writer.Boundary()
    m.SetHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/mixed; boundary="+boundary)

    // Add HTML part
    htmlPart := make(textproto.MIMEHeader)
    htmlPart.Set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
    htmlPartWriter, err := writer.CreatePart(htmlPart)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    htmlPartWriter.Write([]byte(bodyHTML))

    // Add Attachment part
    attachmentPart := make(textproto.MIMEHeader)
    attachmentPart.Set("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
    attachmentPart.Set("Content-Disposition", `attachment; filename="`+attachmentName+`"`)
    attachmentPartWriter, err := writer.CreatePart(attachmentPart)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    attachmentPartWriter.Write(attachmentData)

    writer.Close()

    // Send the email
    auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", "your_email@example.com", "your_password", "smtp.example.com")
    err = smtp.SendMail("smtp.example.com:587", auth, from, to, body.Bytes())
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

import the net/smtp package instead of the gopkg.in/mail.v2 package for sending emails using SMTP.
Also, you should include an  tag with the appropriate src attribute.